# PHPMyAdmin twig syntax visible on page when using PHP 7.0.x or 7.1.x

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, phpbrew

iam using PHPBrew for managing different versions of PHP on my local development system.

When using php-7.0.x or 7.1.x my phpmyadmin (4.9.4) does not render correctly. The twig syntax is visible and i can not use the page.
The Syntax looks something like this: "{% if url is defined and url is iterable and url['href'] is not empty %} {% endif %}"

**Screenshot of PHPMyAdmin**

[image: Screenshot of PHPMyAdmin]

PHPMyAdmin is working with 5.6.x, 7.2.x, 7.3.x.
I tried different variants (small, default, everything, custom) when building the php version, nothing helped.

There is also a JavaScript error "js_array is not defined" when using 7.0 or 7.1 and the page is not usable due the JS Errors.

My System is an OpenSUSE Tumbleweed but also tested on fedora 31.
I am working on a project where php compatibility is 7.1 so using 7.2 is sadly no option and switching between different versions every few minutes is also not ideal.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Maybe your web server doesn't handle `.twig` files. please update it's configuration to handle `.twig` files.

Comment: Thanx for the input, i don't think its the apache server since all other PHP Versions work (Apache stays always the same)